# Prediction of a continuous variable

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models

I'm trying to create a model to predict a continuous variable, that is the revenue of a movie, given many predictors, such as its budget, the length of the film, the genre... I'm planning to use MLP, but I'm not sure on how to deal with the dependent variable: should I bin it in different ranges of revenues? If so, how many classes could work with MLP? If not, what should I do with it?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you have a regression task and you are under the impression that MLPs can only be used for classification. That isn't true. MLPs can be used for regression without turning the dependent variable into a categorical variable: simply use an activation in the last layer that is suitable for regression (like a linear activation)

Comment: For example, see [scikit-learn's MLPRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an MLP for a regression task. A typical loss function would be mean square error, but there are many others with different statistical properties. Likewise, while a classification task usually has a softmax or sigmoid activation on the output, a regression task typically uses the identity function, but you have other options as well.